# r - using multcompLetters to add connecting letters

Tags: r

I hope there is someone who has 2 minutes to explain me 2 things. I have this code that I run on a pretty large dataset. Its using multcompLetters to add connecting letters to my boxplots. I have an experiment setup with 4 treatments and 2 genotypes so my aov is like y ~ Treat+Geno+Geno:Treat. 
When I run the code with the treatment (3df) or interaction (7df) it seems to work quite ok all the time. When I run it on Geno(here x) i get an error.

```
Error in multcompLetters(t$x[, 1]) : Names required for t$x[, 1]
```

And i really cant find out why.

2nd question -

What does the [,4] mean in

```
groups2 <- multcompLetters(t$x[,4])
```

??

The code mockup made for u:

```
#RGR ~ Geno boxplot
y<-c(1,2,6,4,5,7,2,3,9,7,5,6,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,5)
x<-c("no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes",
 "no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes")
fit <- aov(y~x)
summary(fit)
 t <- TukeyHSD(aov(fit))
 t
names(t)
boxplot(y~x, data=For.R, ylim=c(0,10),xlab="Some", ylab="Else")
 tp <- extract_p(t)
 tp
 groups2 <- multcompLetters(t$x[,4])
 lets <- groups2$Letters[c(4,1:3)]
 text(1:4, 95 ,lets)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at `t$x`. What `t$x[,4]` is takes the fourth column, all rows of `t$x`. A better way would have been to say `t$x[,'p adj']` so it is more readable in the code. This is pretty basic R, so you should probably read some tutorials before asking here. Also, I am guessing that you are using the package `multcompView`, which should also be mentioned. You also failed to include data for `For.R` which I imagine is just `data.frame(x=x,y=y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `multcompLetters` expects is a matrix of values, because it is expected more than one comparison. In your data, you only have one comparison, `yes` vs `no`. If you look inside your `t$x` variable, you can see this matrix:

```
t$x
#        diff       lwr      upr    p adj
# yes-no  0.3 -1.631884 2.231884 0.747998
```

Typically, there would be many rows here. Unfortunately, when you select only one row from this matrix, all of the row names get dropped, and `multcompLetters` needs the names. For example:

```
t$x[,4]
# [1] 0.747998 # No names.
```

To prevent this, you have to add a parameter to your subselect:

```
t$x[,4,drop=FALSE] 
#           p adj
# yes-no 0.747998 # Names intact

multcompLetters(t$x[,4,drop=FALSE]) # Works.
# $Letters
# yes-no 
#    "a" 
# 
# $LetterMatrix
#           a
# yes-no TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, in getting one letter. But not in adding a letter on top of each box. I would love to read more up on R, but my paper has a deadline Friday morning, so it gotta be after that.

Comment: This code does the trick. But I can only make it work if I have more than two categories.

Comment: y<-c(1,22,6,42,5,72,2,32,9,72,5,62,4,32,2,32,4,52,4,52,20,21,22,23,24,23,21,21,23,21)
x<-c("no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes",
     "no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","pos"
     ,"pos","pos","pos","pos","pos","pos","pos","pos","pos")
fit <- aov(y~x)
#summary(fit)
t <- TukeyHSD(aov(fit))
#t
#names(t)
boxplot(y~x, data=For.R, ylim=c(0,70),xlab="Some", ylab="Else")
tp <- extract_p(t)
groups2 <- multcompLetters(t$x[,4])
lets <- groups2$Letters[c(3,1:2)]
groups2
lets
text(1:3, 20 ,lets)